# After Effects: Workflow advice, working from/updating archived projects

Tags: after-effects, workflow

I have a question about optimizing my workflow in regards to archiving. I feel like there must be a better way method to what I’m doing at the moment. What I currently do, after I’m done working in a .aep file, is clean up my project, organize my Project panel, get rid of any unused or redundant compositions/files etc., and finally use *File > Dependencies > Collect Files…*, to put everything in one place, and have everything linked up in a concise, local location.

This works great imo. I was wondering however whether it was possible to, say, when working from this new .aep file – adding new files/directories to it, maybe removing some – ‘update’ it in such a way that the directory setup doesn’t change, but all the additional files get added to this directory.

Am I using the *Collect Files…* function wrong? Is it something only used for preparing files for passing them on? Is there a way of working that comes close to what I’m describing? Very curious to hear your guys input or workflow advice. I feel like there’s a better way of working that I’m not utilizing.

Thanks in advance, and kind regards,

Armand

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the right answer, but it's what I do:

Keep everything for your project in a single folder.  Everthing.  Even if it means duplicating things from other projects or from templates that you use all the time.

Regularly back up the folder to another drive.  Use [Chronosync](https://www.econtechnologies.com/chronosync/overview.html) to do this.  It works very reliably, and can do incremental backups intelligently.

When you're done, keep your backups somewhere sensible and delete from your working drives.

This isn't the most space-efficient way to work, but it means you reliably never lose anything.

Collect files takes forever and is complicated.  Chronosync means pressing a single button then forgetting about it.